# Error when using global variables from es5-library in typescript

Tags: dependency-injection, typescript, angular, ecmascript-6

I am developing an app using Angular 2 and Ionic. I am using a bluetooth library for Cordova, so not writing using ES6-modules and exports.

The library defines a global variable called 'bluetoothle', and it works as expected when I run it. However, I get a lot of complaints from the typescript compiler. I would like to either:

- (Preferred) Have some better way to import the ES5-library to my typescript-project.
- Tell the compiler to ignore this error.
- Declare the variable, and then let the library assign value to it(however, I don't know how to declare globals in typescript the way it was possible in ES6.

Thanks in advance, 
Markus

Comment: How are you importing the library?

Comment: I am using Ionic, which in turns wraps Cordova. I imported it though the cordova cli, and I have a xml-file in the cordova-project with the lines:   <js-module src="www/bluetoothle.js" name="BluetoothLe">
    <clobbers target="window.bluetoothle" />
  </js-module>

I guess this is handled internally by cordova in some way.

Comment: Eh, I mean in your typescript file

Comment: As it is defined globally, I simply have a reference to it. I do not import it at all, it is simply there. At runtime this works, but the compiler doesn't understand this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options there which depend on how much work you want to put in them.

The first and easy option is to just declare the variable at the top. This will tell TypeScript that this is a variable of type `any` and that it doesn't need to care about where it came from or which members it has:

```js
declare var bluetoothle;
```

The other route, which would be cleaner but is way more work is writing a [type definition file](http://definitelytyped.org/guides/best-practices.html).

Comment: Awesome! I took the easy route for now, we'll see how it goes. Thanks a lot!